# ARM Assembler BCD to integer w/o multiply instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

For my class I have to write an assembler function, which gets a BCD code from an specific index of a vector as a parameter and returns the equivalent integer value. I may only use a basic ARM instruction set like:

**AND, EOR, SUB, RSB, ADD, CMP, CMN, TST, TEQ, ORR, MOV, BIC, MVN, LSL, LSR, ASR, ROR**

and may NOT use the multiply instruction.

I know how the conversion normally works, but I don't get how it could work without multiplying the single nibbles. Does it have something to do with bit-shifting?

Every hint would be great.

And excuse me if some information are missing, I'm really new to this field.
If any is missing, which could be important - please let me know and I will rich it by.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the trivial way that should have occurred to you is that multiplication is repeated addition, and you can use `ADD`.

A somewhat more sophisticated method is if you realize that `10*x = 8*x + x + x` and multiplication by `8` is a shift by `3` so you can do that using a shift and two additions.

Comment: Or indeed `x*5 + x*5` or `x*5*2`, if only for the wacky "multiply by 5" single-instruction idiom: `add r0, r0, r0 lsl #2`.

Comment: nice and then can save a times two from every digit and do it all at once later.   Saves a few instructions at least.

Answer (score 2):

10*x = 5*2*x = (4+1)*2*x = (4x+x)*2 = ((x<<2)+x)<<1;

EDIT

Yes you have to do single BCD digits.

```
10 = 1010b
100 = 1100100b
1000 = 1111101000b
```

and so on.

so as above 10 can be what Jester said (just look at the bits) (x<<3)+(x<<1). or you could look at it as 5*2  and 5 is 101b  or (x<<2)+x and multiply that by 2   ((x<<2)+x)<<1

100 is (x<<6)+(x<<5)+(x<<2)  or take a 2 from each  ((x<<4)+(x<<3)+x)<<2

or look at this with elementary school math where k,l,m,n are arbitrary bits.

```
    klmn
 *  1010
 =======
    0000 
   klmn
  0000
+klmn
=========
(klmn<<1)+(klmn<<3)
```

the times 100 case you can do as 10*(10*x)  and maybe that is less shifting and adding, maybe not. or factor it out 5*5*2*2*x  can do the 5x and then 5 times that then just shift that result.  Basically all of this we learned in elementary school, it is just way simpler with base 2 since you only need to know the zeros times table and the ones times table.